# Swift: Animating UIButton after auto-formatting UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, switch-statement, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` that only takes numbers. It's a phone number field. Once there are 10 characters in the field (area code + number), I convert the `textField.text` string to an `NSMutableString` to format it to a phone number.

Now, once the format takes place, I need to animate my `UIButton` to let the user continue to the next page in the same format, but the format and button animation don't take place at the same time. I can type 10 characters, auto-format, backspace one character, type another number and the button will display, but never in the same action.

```
@IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumber: UITextField!

    @IBAction func phoneNumberDidChange(sender: AnyObject) {

        switch count(phoneNumber.text) {
        case 10:
            var formattedNumber : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(string: self.phoneNumber.text)
            formattedNumber.insertString("(", atIndex: 0)
            formattedNumber.insertString(")", atIndex: 4)
            formattedNumber.insertString(" ", atIndex: 5)
            formattedNumber.insertString("-", atIndex: 9)
            self.phoneNumber.text = formattedNumber as String
        case 14:
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.submitButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y)
            })
        default:
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.submitButton.center = CGPointMake(self.submitButton.center.x - 400, self.submitButton.center.y)
            })
        }
    }

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        submitButton.center = CGPointMake(submitButton.center.x - 400, submitButton.center.y)

    }
```

How can I get the auto-format and button animation in the same action? When I add the `UIView.animateWithDuration()` to `case 10:` it doesn't get called at all.

Comment: I don't know if this is causing your problem, but if you're using auto layout in IB, you shouldn't be setting the center property, you should be modifying constraints to animate the button's position.

Comment: Nope that wasn't it. The `UIView.animateWithDuration()` is actually getting called because I used a `println()` within the completion handler to test, but the button itself isn't appearing.

Comment: Are you using auto layout? Even if that's not your immediate problem, you still should set frames (or centers) when using auto layout.

Comment: Yeah the `UIButton` is set to the horizontal and vertical centers, height, and trailing/leading spaces to margins

Comment: Feels like it has something to do with the `count(phoneNumber.text)` not auto-refreshing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have auto layout turned on, you should do it something like this,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var centerCon: NSLayoutConstraint! // IBOutlet to a centerX constraint on the button

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        centerCon.constant = self.view.frame.size.width/2 + submitButton.frame.size.width // puts the button just off screen to the left
    }


    @IBAction func phoneNumberDidChange(sender: AnyObject) {

        switch count(phoneNumber.text) {
        case 10:
            var formattedNumber : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(string: self.phoneNumber.text)
            formattedNumber.insertString("(", atIndex: 0)
            formattedNumber.insertString(")", atIndex: 4)
            formattedNumber.insertString(" ", atIndex: 5)
            formattedNumber.insertString("-", atIndex: 9)
            self.phoneNumber.text = formattedNumber as String

            self.centerCon.constant = 0
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })

        case 14
             self.centerCon.constant = 0
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })

        default:
            centerCon.constant = self.view.frame.size.width/2 + submitButton.frame.size.width
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Your case 14 never gets called, because formatting the string in code doesn't call your phoneNumberDidChange: function (only user entry in the text field calls it). In the code above, notice that the animation is called in both case 10 (so it happens right after the formatting), and also in case 14 (in case you back space and then add more numbers).

Comment: The button doesn't show at all. The compiler tells me it's attempting to recover by breaking constraints and to make a symbolic breakpoint at `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`

Comment: @DavidPerkins  You should delete the leading and trailing constraints to your button. You only need the centerX and centerY.

Comment: Ah yes that works. But without the leading and trailing constraints my button (which should span the width of the screen) is short. How would I set the width constraint programmatically?

Comment: @DavidPerkins You don't need to set it programmatically. You can give it a width constraint in IB. Either a fixed number, or you can make it equal to the superview's width (minus any padding you want).